# WinForms key press isn't working right

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

**update**: I've modified the code below to reveal some additional information regarding the key that was pressed.

**update #2**: I've discovered the root cause of the issue: we have an HTML control (Gecko rendering engine) on our form. When that Gecko rendering engine navigates to some Flash control, suddenly ~2% of our key presses don't get through, even after we've removed the Gecko HTML control. Wahoo, I get to blame this on Flash! Now the question is, how do I fix this?

**update #3**: Nope, it's not Flash. It's the Gecko rendering engine. Navigating even to Google causes some keys to not come through to our app right. Hrmmm.

We have a strange case in our WinForms app where the user presses a key combination (in this case, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), and WinForms tells us some other key combo (value 262162) is pressed:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(keyData == (Keys.S | Keys.Alt))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You pressed Alt+S");
    }
    else if(keyData == (Keys.Menu | Keys.Alt))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("What the hell?"); // This sometimes gets hit when I press Alt+S
    }
}
```

90% of the time, `You pressed Alt+S` will be shown. But on rare occurrances, we press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and it says, `What the hell?`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe 10% of the time you're actually pressing the Alt key after the S?

Comment: Well the Alt key is 262144.  To get 262162, you would have to add 18.  18 corresponds to the letter S (with A = 0), but this might just be a coincidence.  But I can't explain why sometimes it using the Keys.S constant (83) and 18!

Could it be affected by the order in which the keys are pressed?  Keys.Menu enumeration is 18

Comment: @MusiGenesis, nope, I'm certain I'm pressing Alt+S in the same order as usual. Something funny is going on...maybe some 3rd party control eating keys or something...can't identify the problem.

Comment: @Chris, S = 83 according to WinForms. Offhand, I believe A = 65.

Comment: @Chris 18 corresponds to (Keys.Rbutton | Keys.ShiftKey). What the hell? So 262162 == (Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt). WTF?

Comment: Is your cat sitting on your mouse?  Seriously, that's messed me up before with keyboard stuff.

Comment: Justin's answer tells me that Keys.Menu == (Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey). And Keys.Menu is "the alt key". Ummm...ok, not sure how that's different than Keys.Alt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** I've discovered the root cause of the issue! See below.

<strike>After more experimenting, I've found that if do the following, it works as expected:</strike>

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
...
private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && e.Alt)
   {
        // This always works.
   }
}
```

I can't explain why the ProcessCmdKey didn't work. I wish I knew. Until then, this is an acceptable workaround.

I've discovered the issue. We have an HTML control (Gecko rendering engine) on our form. When that gecko rendering engine is shown on a form, it must be installing a hook or something that changes some key presses, causing us to receive WM_Char instead of WM_KeyDown in certain cases.

Comment: You'll want to make sure to set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property to get the functionality you'll want.  Look here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx

Comment: Sounds similar to an old battle we had with the .NET WebBrowser and it's screwy behavior with Flash (and other things).  Have fun with it, sir!

Comment: In my case, that's all because some other software register the same hot key.

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, it would appear that 262162 would be the "Alt" key.

**Edit**:  I overrode the ProcessCmdKey and put in a break point on the "X = 1;" statement:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        int x = (int)keyData;
        if (x == 262162)
            x = 1;
        return true;
    }
```

It hits that breakpoint whenever I hit the Alt key.

Comment: Console.WriteLine((int)Keys.Alt); // prints 262144

Comment: Edit: Heh, you're right. So what the heck -- why isn't Alt+S working? When it doesn't work, I hear the Windows "ding" sound played, like there's no shortcut registered. Strange...what's going on?

Comment: Your code would work if you eliminate your "else if" condition.  You should'nt have to worry about cases where "Alt-S" isn't being pressed.  The "ding" may be coming in if your keypress code is causing the buffer to overflow.

Comment: `return true;` kills the event that might land in KeyPress afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Could it be that you are waiting too long to press the <kbd>S</kbd> key and an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key repeat is getting fired off?</strike>

EDIT2:I tried you posted code and I receive "What the Hell" the second I touch the ALT key, however if I disable this check the Alt-S always comes through. On my system this seems to be the default key code for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I am able to ignore it and the Alt-S Will come through afterwards.

EDIT: According to the METADATA for the Keys enumeration Keys.Menu is 18. To see this hit <kbd>F12</kbd> while the cursor is on the Keys Enumeration.

The documentation states that Keys.Menu is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

This tells me that it is reporting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key was pressed(18) with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key modifier(262144) crazy stuff.

Comment: RE: *"Could it be that you are waiting too long to press the S key and an Alt key repeat is getting fired off?"* I don't think so; I tried holding down the Alt key for about 10 seconds, then hitting S. It still registered as Alt+S.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about the Menu key. Looking at var menu = Keys.Menu in the debugger, it shows the value as (Keys.Rbutton | Keys.ShiftKey).

Comment: RE:"Looking at var menu = Keys.Menu in the debugger, it shows the value as (Keys.Rbutton | Keys.ShiftKey)" I see that same thing. Even if I hover over Keys.Menu

After receiving "What the Hell" does the Alt-S eventually post?

Comment: I tried you posted code and I receive "What the Hell" the second I touch the ALT key, however if I disable this check the Alt-S always comes through.

Comment: Ok. That was pseudo code of course; the original was just checking for Alt+S, never for anything else. Occassionally, Alt+S has no effect, other than to set off the "windows ding" sound from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity could you try this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.S | Keys.Alt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You pressed Alt+S");
        }
        else if (keyData == (Keys.Menu | Keys.Alt))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

returning false indicates that this is not a command key.